# How to change orientation in tig status view

Tags: git, tig

[image]

I need to swicth between landscape and portrait orientations in **tig** status view cause sometimes diff line doesn't fit to right part of view.

Comment: I'm a bit curious about how you got tig to use landscape mode, since I  can't find anything about it in the documentation. How did you do?

Comment: @iveqy Since version 2.0, Tig will (by default) automatically switch to landscape mode when the terminal is wider than 160 characters.

Comment: @iveqy Forgot to mention that landscape orientation is supported before version 2.0 by setting `vertical-split` to true in your `~/.tigrc`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can change the orientation use the `vertical-split` option. In version 2.0, it is set to `auto` by default, which will use a heuristics to determine whether to use landscape or portrait orientation (note: in the Tig docs this is called *horizontal* and *vertical* split).

Following is the option's documentation for version 2.0:

> **vertical-split** *(mixed) [auto|]*
>
> Whether to split the view horizontally or vertically. "auto" (which is the default) means   that it will depend on the window dimensions. When true vertical orientation is used, and false sets the orientation to horizontal.

Comment: it is possible to fix the width of the left window in vertical split?, in order to give more space to the diff  in the status view

Comment: @mauricio-sánchez, add `set split-view-width = 60%` to `~/.tigrc`

Comment: Alternative values: `horizontal|vertical`. Add the line `set vertical-split = horizontal` to the `~/.tigrc` to always split horizontally

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to have the possibility to view a single commit in landscape mode, you can select your commit in the main view and then press `d`, this will bring you to a full-screen diff view which is colored and scrollable.